# Retrieve SAML logs using Google API, with powershell

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-api, saml

I would like to retrieve all SAML logs using Google API (I'm using a powershell script to run this task).
I getting the following error while trying to execute the GET request : `"Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records."`

These are the steps I followed :

1. Created a Google Cloud Platform project and enable the "Admin SDK API"
2. Created a service account and download the key in JSON
3. Registered the service account with it's client ID with "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly" scope on Google admin console (Domain-wide Delegation configuration)
4. With the provided credentials (JSON file) created a certificate and a JWT token (see the code below)
5. Obtained an access token an performed a GET request

`

```
$cert = $cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath "./cer.pfx" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString "..." -AsPlainText -Force) # The service account credentials

$now = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$createDate = [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date($now) -UFormat "%s"))
$expiryDate = [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date($now.AddHours(1)) -UFormat "%s"))

$rawclaims = [Ordered]@{
    iss = "test@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com" # Your service account
    scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly"
    aud = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
    sub = "test@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    iat = $createDate
    exp = $expiryDate
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Encoding the JWT claim set
$jwt = New-Jwt -PayloadJson $rawclaims -Cert $cert #-Verbose
# Making the access token request
$apiendpoint = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
$splat = @{
    Method      = "POST"
    Uri         = $apiendpoint
    ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Body        = "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=$jwt"
}

# Get access token to authenticate with SPN
try {
    $res = Invoke-RestMethod @splat -Verbose
}
catch {
    [Console]::Error.WriteLine("Error during GCP authentication : $_")
}

# Get SAML logs
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($res.access_token)"
}
$uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/saml"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers
$response
```

`

Thank you

Comment: You do not have permission to access the files.  You may set admin to a different project or didn't enable the correct permissions.  See : https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158846?hl=en&force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `"Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records."` appears because the user that is performing the API call doesn't have access to the reports, in this case the service account.

- I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402119/how-to-deal-with-access-denied-you-are-not-authorized-to-read-activity-records) where it is mentioned that you need to impersonate an Admin in order to access the reports.
- Examples from Google in different programming languages show that an admin email is being impersonated:

  - [Java](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/guides#use)
- Based on [this sample code](https://gist.github.com/SP3269/da43b00692de5b3f591b3068d76df577) you can use the `sub` parameter to set the email address of the Admin to impersonate:

```
$rawclaims = [Ordered]@{
    iss = "test@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com" # Your service account
    scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly"
    aud = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
    sub = "admin@yourgoogleworkspacedomain.com" # The user to impersonate
    iat = $createDate
    exp = $expiryDate
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Bryan. Indeed I had to impersonate a user email instead of a service account email. It works now perfectly