# PowerShell: Accessing Google Analytics GA4 using a Service Account and JSON File

Tags: powershell, google-analytics, google-oauth

I need to get data from Google Analytics GA4 via API.  I have created a service account and downloaded the JSON file.  See below for an partial copy of the file.  I need to use PowerShell and have not had any luck figuring out how to get the tokens for AUTH 2.0 to actually do the API call.  I don't know if I need to load a module, but suggestions would be welcome.  I don't have a secret code so all of the examples I looked at would not work.  If someone can share your knowledge I would gratefully appreciate it.

Sample JSON file
{
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": "ccc-pull-16
"private_key_id": "313a20f
"private_key": "-----BEGIN
"client_email": "starting-
"client_id": "106846481226
"auth_uri": "https://accou
"token_uri": "https://oaut
"auth_provider_x509_cert_u
"client_x509_cert_url": "h
"universe_domain": "google
}

Existing Code:
I have not tried as I don't have the proper understanding of what I have to do.

Comment: Have a look at this it should be similar just need to change the scope https://stackoverflow.com/q/76013275/1841839   Just try searching for powershell google service account there are a few examples around.